# image url with question mark

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-applications

In the following script the url of some video source are gotten from a json and played on a web interface.

The urls are like this:  http://ip:port/resource?user=blabla&pwd=blablabla
when the page is loaded in the firefox console i find:

```
GET http://ip:port/resource
```

the question mark and all following chars are omitted.

So the device do not receive the well formed url and the streaming do not starts.

```
function getData(){

    var deviceParams = {};

    $.ajax({

        url: "cameras.json",

        //dataType: 'json',

    dataType: 'json',

        success: function(data) {

        /* Dinamically adding cams div */

    var camsList = $("#cams_ul");

        var availableCams = formatDeviceParams(data.deviceParams);

        var videoSrc = "";

        availableCams.forEach(function(cam, index){ 

            videoSrc = "http://" + cam.ip + ":" + cam.port + cam.video_url;


        camsList.append('<div class="panel-video panel panel-primary col-md-3 col-xs-5 col-xxs-10">'
               +cam.device_name+
            '<div class="panel-body"><img class="videovid" src="'+videoSrc+'"/></div></div>');
    });



        /* ======= jQuery Modal section ======= */

        var images = document.getElementsByClassName('videodiv');
        for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            images[i].onclick = function(){
                openNav();
                $("#modal-image").attr("src", this.src);
            }
        }
        /* ====== END Modal section ===== */
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
The problem was only on firefox visualizzation.
Executing the script, the firefox's console showes only the main address http://ip:port/resource omitting the cars after the question mark, but the GET generated includes the well formed url: http://ip:port/resource?admin=blabla&pwd=blablabla